Unable to install R package 'cacc'
I'm trying to install the cacc package in R using the instructions here and after running install.packages("cacc"), an error is displayed:
installing the source package ‘cacc’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/cacc_0.1.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 30751 bytes (30 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 30 KB

* installing *source* package ‘cacc’ ...
** package ‘cacc’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
Error in parse(outFile) : 
  /[filepath here]/R.INSTALL27c669724e91/cacc/R/cacc.R:31:25: unexpected '>'
30:   # Count all profiles
31:   matrix_total <- data |>
                            ^
ERROR: unable to collate and parse R files for package ‘cacc’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/cacc’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘cacc’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/[filepath here]/downloaded_packages’

Am I doing something wrong (or is there something I can do to resolve it - if so what?) or is there an issue with the package that the package owner needs to fix? If there's something I can do to resolve this, please explain it to me like I'm a complete newbie, so I know what to do step by step.

You need to upgrade from R 4.0 as it doesn't support the native pipe |>, so can't parse the file. You need at least 4.1 but should use the most recent version (4.4.1) unless you have good reason not to.

Good catch. They say on cran that the requirement is R (≥ 2.10). Clearly not the case though as the source code does contain |> pipes. Swapping them for dplyr pipes %>% would fix the base R requirements. Maybe something they want to address.

issue submitted: https://github.com/amoneva/cacc/issues/1
